# Listener '$cordovaLocalNotification:trigger' not triggered where as '$cordovaLocalNotification:scheduled' is working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, uilocalnotification, ios10, ngcordova

This is ionic(Not ionic v2) with angularjs. 
When a local notification is scheduled, I see '$cordovaLocalNotification:schedule' getting triggered but not '$cordovaLocalNotification:trigger'.

```
   $rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:schedule',
        function (event, notification, state) {
            // ...
            alert("Local Notification scheduled");
        });

    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:trigger',
        function (event, notification, state) {
            // ...
            alert("Local Notification triggered")
        });
```

Providing the methods below using which notifications are triggered:

```
$rootScope.scheduleNotification = function (title,notificationMessage) {
    $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
      id: 1,
      title: title,
      text: notificationMessage,
      data: {
        customProperty: 'custom value'
      }
    }).then(function (result) {
      // ...
    });
  };
```

All the injections are set and I presume without that scheduled listener will not work!

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't schedule this notification for a specific date and time? Perhaps the issues are caused by the fact that this notification is triggered as soon as it is scheduled.

Comment: @Dexter: Apparently, I googled alot(literally) to find that with iOS 10 release, plugin available through ngcordova doesn't work anymore to trigger a notification and needs tweaks per se importing `UserNotificaitions` into iOS code of plugin. and a work around is provided by a different volunteer on top of available one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling found that, tweaking of existing plugin [katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) is necessary to support **iOS 10 changes** to **Push Notification & LocalNotifications** to support the new Notification center features.

As a temporary fix, do the below:

1. ionic plugin rm de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification
2. ionic plugin add https://github.com/spk0611/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#9ad32cf2059cdf9a54b4930b1c58ba76ef7e3a87
3. Go to Xcode and ensure that *XCode -> Preferences -> Locations* and check if *Command Line Tools is set to Xcode 8*.(I am really not aware why this is done)
4. while in Xcode, go to the build settings for your target and be certain “Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)” is turned on
5. finally, edit plugin.xml (it’s in the plugins folder of the added one) to uncomment the line that commented out the cordova-plugman engine in order for the app to actually have access to the plugin.

[add plugin from here](https://github.com/spk0611/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#9ad32cf2059cdf9a54b4930b1c58ba76ef7e3a87)

[Solution Source](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/pull/1093)

And Hurray! I got it working :-)

Comment: I encountered the same problem with Cordova plugins breaking after upgrading from Xcode 7 to Xcode 8.1. I was lost, but thanks to your post I was able to deploy to an iPhone device with iOS 10 with Local Push Notifications working again! I only had to follow your steps 1, 2, and 5.